# Generate form with simple_form view erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to generate a for with simple_form. I have the gem in Gemfile, ran `bundle install` and `generate simple_form:install`

This is new.html.erb :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <% simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.input  :image %>
    <%= f.input  :caption %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
    <% end %>
</body>
</html>
```

My post_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index 
    end

    def new
      @post = Post.new
    end
end
```

My model post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :image, presence: true

    has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => '640x'}
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
    validates :image, presence: true

end
```

And my routes.rb :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  root 'posts#index' 
end
```

- I don't get any errors, but when I load the view with localhost I only see a plain white page
- When I inspect the view generated with the browser's tools, I see all html tags, but no erb.
- When I delete the erb and write something like `Test`, I can see **Test** in the browser

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code, any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you missed `=` in this code: `<% simple_form_for @post do |f| %>`.
You can do this as follows:

```
<body>
 <%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.input  :image %>
  <%= f.input  :caption %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
 <% end %>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. How is that different to what I already have?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought that first line of code never had the `=`.

Comment: Actually I'm just checking other examples of loops in erb, and they don't seem to have that `=`. I'll have to google around to see how it works

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this link https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form, there in the example they have used `<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>`